# SQL Database Help - MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, field, autofill, workbench

I have a table for Staff, which holds all their key data; StaffID, Name, address etc. There is also a table for Absences. The Absences table has Absence ID, Staff ID, Staff Name and Date.
Is there a way to autofill the Staff Name field in Absences when the Staff ID is entered.
So a way for the database to look up the Staff name associated with that specific ID?

Or whenever an absence is recorded, do I have to manually insert ID and Name (The problem with this is someone could accidentally put a name that doesn't match the ID)

Any ideas/help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should better understand the concept behind **Relational Databases**.  What you are trying to do is to replicate data, which leads to operational inefficiencies,  errors, duplicate data, and a long list of problems.  Check your database design and implement **keys** and **indexes**.  The absentee name should be kept in just one table, instead of entering in different tables. What you re trying to do is an horror nightmare in the scope of a fit information system.

Comment: What I am hoping to achieve is to have this database linked up to my Java Code, and when a method - addAbsence() is called, the user will simply add the Staff ID of the staff who is absent, and the database will automatically fill in the Name of the Staff and the Date

Comment: ok, in that case,  simply populate fields when the method is calledd, that is,  submit a query where the condition is the staffer id,  to query staffer name and other data,  the result should populate your form fields.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this.

1. `Insert Trigger` when new record is added you want to go to additional table and get name that can be inserted into `Absences` table.
2. Modify your application to look-up data from `STAFF` table and during insert add that data.
3. Run update statement that will get name from `STAFF` and place it in `Absences`.

This all depends on how you want to implement it. Your best alternative would be `INSERT` trigger. Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html for how to use triggers in MySQL

Comment: Thank you, I am new to MySQL so although the answer may have seem obvious, this was very helpful for me.

Comment: Read up on `INSERT Trigger` that would be best way and at same time will help you to learn workings of MySQL